# Android, selecting a Cipher suite

Tags: android, encryption

I have the code base for an application but I cannot see where I can find the cipher suite it uses when making outbound connections. Can anyone point me in the right direction. When I open the project in Android Studio right click app-> open module settings -> Flavors tab -> Min Sdk Version is set to 15, Target Sdk Version is set to API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Thanks,
P

Comment: What do you mean by "Cipher suite"?

Comment: See Cipher Suites on https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Examples: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA etc

Comment: Did you implement networking?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by the question

Answer (score 2):

Cipher suite used depends on server ssl certificate and ciphers it supports. You can check available cipher suits for different Android versions here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html

Note the following fragment:

> These kinds of protection are specified by a "cipher suite", which is
>   a combination of cryptographic algorithms used by a given SSL
>   connection. During the negotiation process, the two endpoints must
>   agree on a cipher suite that is available in both environments. If
>   there is no such suite in common, no SSL connection can be
>   established, and no data can be exchanged.

As you see, your Android 5.0 can use many different suites depending on the certificate type.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you can't programmitcally select a cipher suite, that selection is made during the handshake between client/server. So how do you ensure for example, that the cipher suite that will be selected will be a TLSv1.2 version? Do I upgrade certs on both sides?

Comment: You should only set correct suite for your server and client will have to agree on it or cancel connection.